# how to handle delays when web pages get long to load?

Tags: watin

I am doing some unit testing using watin. but the problem is when a web page gets too long to load, the test automation fails because the required element is still not available but the control action is already executed in watin.

Answer (score 4):

Just set `Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut` to wait as many seconds as you need.

Comment: @Thilina Fonseka: `WatiN.Core.Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 120` for 2 minutes. Maybe you also need to set `WatiN.Core.Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut`.

Comment: WaitForCompleteTimeOut is to wait for the page to be fully loaded. WaitUntilExistsTimeOut is to wait for an element to "showup" on a page, mainly usefull when dom elements are dynamically created on a page.